# Apache AH01997: SSL handshake failed: sending 502

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, openssl

Trying to create a virtual host proxying to an application hosted on Openshift with a really nasty url. When trying to do this I find the following error in the log file

> AH01997: SSL handshake failed: sending 502

and in the browser the following is shown

> Proxy Error
>   The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.
>   Reason: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server

Which I first thought had something to do with the cipher, but...I do not think so now. So I must admit that I am really not sure what the root cause can be.

### Apache info

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.38 (Win64)
Server built:   Jan 17 2019 19:32:38
```

### Apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile      ${cert_file}
SSLCertificateKeyFile   ${cert_key}

DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/mattermost/443"

ServerName mattermost.mycorp.com
ServerAlias mattermost.mycorp.com

LogLevel trace6
ErrorLog d:/logs/prod/prod_error_443_mattermost.mycorp.com.log
CustomLog d:/logs/prod/prod_access_443_mattermost.mycorp.com.log mycorpdirect env=!forwarded
CustomLog d:/logs/prod/prod_access_443_mattermost.mycorp.com.log mycorpproxy env=forwarded


SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName Off
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
SSLProxyProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
SSLProxyCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyVia On

#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule ^(/.*)  https://mattermost-kalypso.cloudappsk2.11913.2016.dcs.mycorp.com/ [P]
ProxyPass / https://mattermost-kalypso.cloudappsk2.11913.2016.dcs.mycorp.com/

ProxyPassReverse / https://mattermost-kalypso.cloudappsk2.11913.2016.dcs.mycorp.com/
```

### Apache error log

```
[Thu May 09 15:05:02.694205 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 5668:tid 1836] [remote yy.yy.yy.yy:443] AH02003: SSL Proxy connect failed
[Thu May 09 15:05:02.694205 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 5668:tid 1836] [remote yy.yy.yy.yy:443] AH01998: Connection closed to child 0 with abortive shutdown (server mattermost.mycorp.com:443)
[Thu May 09 15:05:02.694205 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 5668:tid 1836] [remote yy.yy.yy.yy:443] AH01997: SSL handshake failed: sending 502
[Thu May 09 15:05:02.694205 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 5668:tid 1836] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client yyy.yy.y.yyy:65148] AH01084: pass request body failed to yy.yy.yy.yy:443 (mattermost-kalypso.cloudappsk2.11913.2016.dcs.mycorp.com), referer: https://mattermost.mycorp.com/
[Thu May 09 15:05:02.694205 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 5668:tid 1836] [client yyy.yy.y.yyy:65148] AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /favicon.ico, referer: https://mattermost.mycorp.com/
[Thu May 09 15:05:02.694205 2019] [proxy_http:error] [pid 5668:tid 1836] [client yyy.yy.y.yyy:65148] AH01097: pass request body failed to yy.yy.yy.yy:443 (mattermost-kalypso.cloudappsk2.11913.2016.dcs.mycorp.com) from yyy.yy.y.yyy (), referer: https://mattermost.mycorp.com/
```

### OpenSSl s_client output

Not all, but the most important stuff ref. my vhost config - tlsv1.2 and the cipher suite

```
SSL-Session:
Protocol  : TLSv1.2
Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

Also verified that Apache has the suite

```
openssl.exe ciphers "TLSv1.2"

TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
.....
```

### All from openssl

```
CONNECTED(00000134)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = *.cloudappsk2.11913.2016.dcs.mycorp.com
   i:CN = openshift-signer@1552839230
 1 s:CN = openshift-signer@1552839230
   i:CN = openshift-signer@1552839230
 2 s:CN = openshift-signer@1552839230
   i:CN = openshift-signer@1552839230
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = *.cloudappsk2.11913.2016.dcs.mycorp.com
issuer=CN = openshift-signer@1552839230
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3089 bytes and written 480 bytes
Verification error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
Protocol  : TLSv1.2
Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Session-ID: FB52D3CDAC5F480496BC3E0F98973AE6C13632C8E861EC19884297167067D019
Session-ID-ctx:
Master-Key: 69EF2D7DE36E00753847C99431478828A7E1F55E756E0D282472AB251F85E43404C1940175C2BD0B12EE2537CD7FB148
PSK identity: None
PSK identity hint: None
SRP username: None
TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
TLS session ticket:
Start Time: 1557334640
Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
Extended master secret: no
---
HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>
Your browser didn't send a complete request in time.
</body></html>
closed
```

Comment: random guess: is your endpoint https enabled?
what is your endpoint telling you in your logs?
whats the openssl output to your endpoint?

Comment: Yes, https is enabled. Self signed cert. Added the whole OpenSSL log now.

Comment: while i'm not 100% certain for me it looks like your proxy (apache) needs more info about the self signed certificate, which seems it is shown in the openssl log as well.

never had to deal with that in apache directly, but my guess would go in the direction of: make apache aware of you intermediate/root CA from the self-signed cert.

Comment: see for additional ideas here: it seems that person has a similiar issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872482/error-during-ssl-handshake-with-remote-server
please note that i suggest you fix your ssl related issue instead of disabling the ssl-verification

Comment: Why are you bothering with the Apache proxy? Just add a route in OpenShift with the desired hostname, and then you can send traffic directly to it.

Comment: Well, yes off course the best thing would be to have the cert in a truststore, but since all certificate checking is disabled for the proxy...that should not be an issue now. Frustrated about the log not saying what excatly is the error. I've read about others using Wireshark and such, but that is for now a bit to hard core for me (until I have tried it at least)

Comment: ...and if I had the option to choose, off course I would not use Apache for this purpose, it would then have been BigIp, but ... we do not have it available to serve this purpose.